# How to replace some HTML contents from files_get_content variable?

Tags: php, html, css

```
$a='/';
$myvar = $_GET['formVar'];
$companies=$_GET['companies'];
$url="https://name.com/" .$companies .$a .$myvar;
$data=file_get_contents($url);
echo $data;
```

I want to replace/remove some  HTML content from page referenced in the `$url` variable.

Comment: [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php) and [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php) do what you want.

Comment: You can not replace the content on the actual page, just in the `$data` variable. Also please tell us what you want to replace/remove for further assist

Comment: Perhaps a more robust way would be to create a DOMDocument object with the HTML returned from `file_get_contents()` - presuming that you expect HTML to be returned. This would likely be a cleaner way to add.remove HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

edit in this way:

```
$a='/';
$myvar = $_GET['formVar'];
$companies=$_GET['companies'];
$url="https://name.com/" .$companies .$a .$myvar;
$data=strip_tags(file_get_contents($url));
echo $data;
```